# Trouble Generating PDF with CakePHP and CakePdf

Tags: cakephp, dompdf

I am trying to use CakePdf to generate a pdf file within CakePHP. I have a function in the CourseGradesController called viewReport. I want viewReport to allow you to select a student from a select field, and then upon submitting the form, it will generate a PDF with the appropriate data. If I put the data into a table and do not try to make a PDF, the page will display correctly, so I don't think that is the problem. In bootstrap.php, I have

```
CakePlugin::load('CakePdf', array('bootstrap' => true, 'routes' => true));
Configure::write('CakePdf', array(
    'engine' => 'CakePdf.WkHtmlToPdf',
    'options' => array(
        'print-media-type' => false,
        'outline' => true,
        'dpi' => 96
    ),
    'margin' => array(
        'bottom' => 15,
        'left' => 50,
        'right' => 30,
        'top' => 45
    ),
    'binary' => '/var/www/cakephp/app/Plugin/CakePdf/Vendor/WkHtmlToPdf',
    'orientation' => 'landscape',
    'download' => false
));
```

I have the WkHtmlToPdf folder moved into /var/www/cakephp/app/Plugin/CakePdf/Vendor/WkHtmlToPdf, so the lib and include folders are in that directory.

In the viewReport function of CourseGradesController, I have

```
    function viewReport($id = null)
    {
        $this->CourseGrade->id = $id;
            if (!$this->CourseGrade->exists()) 
            {
                throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid invoice'));
            }
            $this->pdfConfig = array(
                'orientation' => 'portrait',
                'filename' => 'Invoice_' . $id
            );
            $this->set('invoice', $this->CourseGrade->read(null, $id));
        ...

    }
```

If I navigate to /courseGrades/viewReport, I get the error "Error: The requested address '/cakephp/courseGrades/viewReport' was not found on this server."

If I naviate to /courseGrades/viewReport/1.pdf, then I just see a completely blank screen.

Comment: A few notes: 1) you should update your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16845142/264628) with relevant information when possible instead of starting a new question (though this does cover a new problem, presumably the original problem needs to be resolved); 2) Don't `require_once` dompdf.php, this is an add-on script that uses the dompdf class, not part of the class itself; 3) you shouldn't need to `spl_autoload_register('DOMPDF_autoload');` since this happens via dompdf_config.inc.php.

Comment: As for your CakePHP problems... you show the code for the getStudentReport_pdf action, is it the same for getStudentReport. Also, are you sure `$this->Post->read()` is returning anything? Try `$post = $this->Post->read()` then `debug($post)` to see if the data is being retrieved. FYI, you don't need to specify any parameters to the read() method since you've already set the model ID earlier in the code.

Comment: I made a new question because I decided to try this method since more people seemed to have used it. I made the changes that you suggested though, and I updated my code in the post, but I am getting the same problem.

Comment: Well, first try to address the errors. Regarding the "Indirect modification" error see the following note in the migration guide: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html#models

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend the use of this plugin for this kind of work.

https://github.com/ceeram/CakePdf

Comment: I am trying to use this plugin, but I am still running into problems. What I am trying to do, is you select a student in the viewReport function of the CourseGradesController. After submitting that student, it regenerates that page as a PDF with the students report information added in. I now get an error saying that the page is not found though when I try to reload it.